# Pass form values across views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-2.0

In my first view I want to select a number in my form and have my second view include a check within a checkbox for that selected number.

How can I pass values from view1 to view2?

Answer (score 0):

You could save your check box value in `cookies` then in page2,you can get the value and you can display the check box.

or using rails `params` you could send your value and you can show the check box.